# Small, fading native notification in android application w/ phonegap

Tags: javascript, notifications, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I looked up the related documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#Notification , but could not find how to trigger this kind of message in a hibrid application:

I just wanted to be sure about that it is not included in the phonegap library.

I also would like to know this kind of message's official name :).

Anybody can confirm? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question was posted more than 2 years ago, but I just stumbled upon it today.. You must already know the answer by now, but for someone else visiting this question looking for answer.. I think you are looking for Android Toast, and if so, the answer would be found at [How to create toast in phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724053/how-to-create-toast-in-phonegap)